# OperationalError('near "?": syntax error')

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

Мне нужно поместить в столбец значение "1" при этом имя столбца хранится в переменной "link_for_channel" поэтому я делаю всё через знак вопроса. Но у меня вылазит ошибка.

База Данных:

```
def Add_StatusSubscription(self, link_for_channel):
   with self.conn:
      return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'DataBase' (?) VALUES (1)", (link_for_channel,))
```

Основной код:

```
balance = 0
num = 0
people = 0
rand = 0
i = 3

def check_sub_channel(chat_member):
    print(chat_member.status)
    if chat_member.status != 'left':
        return True
    else:
        return False


def Menu(message: types.Message):
    global num
    global rand
    global i

    if message.chat.type == 'private':

        rand = random.randint(10, 25)

        markup_Inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1) # Активация клавиатуры
        Inline_B1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="↗️Перейти в канал", url=channels_URL[i]) # добавление кнопки с именем
        Inline_B2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="✅Я выполнил!", callback_data="SUB_CHECK") # добавление кнопки с именем
        markup_Inline.add(Inline_B1, Inline_B2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f"⭐️<b>Доступно новое задание на {rand}₽:</b>\n\nПерейди в канал, подпишись, возвращайся сюда и жми кнопку 'Я выполнил'", parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup_Inline)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,MISTAKE)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def menu_check(message: types.Message):
    global people
    global channels_URL

    if message.chat.type == 'private':
    
        get_column_names=conn.execute("select * from PandaDataBase limit 1")
        channels_URL=[i[0] for i in get_column_names.description] # получение всех имён всех столбцов


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def Reply_buttons(message):
    if message.text == 'Задание':
        Menu(message)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    global balance
    global rand
    global i
    USER_ID = call.from_user.id
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data=="SUB_CHECK":
                print("1")
                if check_sub_channel(bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, user_id=USER_ID)):
                    bot.edit_message_text(text=TRY_SUB_MESSAGE, chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup_Inline_Next_Task)
                    db.Add_StatusSubscription(link_for_channel=channels_URL[i]) # Вот заветная строка

                    balance += rand
                    i += 1

###########################    ЗАПУСК БОТА    ################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

[image: База данных]

Comment: А разве можно вообще названия столбцов подставлять в запрос? Вроде только значения можно подставлять

Comment: вместо `?` поставьте `%s`

Comment: @CrazyElf Вот мне тоже интересно стало

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Попробовал разные варианты с  %s , но теперь ошибка OperationalError('near "%": syntax error') . Щас добавлю код

Comment: А нафига `'DataBase'` в кавычках?

Comment: @Namerek Не знаю), я щас попробовал без ковычек , ничего не изменилось

Comment: @CrazyElf, вроде бы нельзя (Ну в python-sqlite по крайней мере)

Comment: Я знаю что можно подставлять в известный столбец , значение из переменной . А чтобы наоборот такого ещё не видел

Comment: @Artem, Это как раз тот редкий случай, когда целесообразно использовать `f` строку, поскольку по другому никак `f"INSERT INTO DataBase ({link_for_channel}) VALUES (1)"` правда придется следить, чтобы в `link_for_channel` не оказалось `None`

Comment: @Artem, или вот так `"INSERT INTO DataBase (%s) VALUES (1);" % link_for_channel`

Comment: @Artem, ну а в общих чертах отвечу цитатой кого-то из завсегдатаев этого ресурса. `"Если Вам это понадобилось, значит что-то Вы делаете неправильно"`

Comment: Что в первом, что во втором варианте ошибка : OperationalError('unrecognized token: ":"')

Comment: А можно DDL таблицы `DataBase` глянуть?